# Implementing a tooltip on a trackbar in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, trackbar

I am trying to implement a trackbar with a tooltip. What I want is that the tooltip to appear at certain values when the trackbar is scrolling and then disappear ( and appear at the x,y coordinate of that value). 
I have been able to get the tooltip up and running but unfortunately it appears all the time when the mouse hovers over the trackbar.

Using .NET framework 2.0

Any help/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Same question here: [how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-showing-the-value-of-a-trackbar-in-winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892369/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-showing-the-value-of-a-trackbar-in-winforms).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a tooltip showing the value of a trackbar in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892369/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-showing-the-value-of-a-trackbar-in-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

You need this overload of [Tooltip.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3s20as1.aspx)

Comment: This is correct, although somewhat incomplete. There's nothing built-in for this—all the built-in functionality can do is show it in response to general mouse events. You'll have to show the tooltip manually whenever the trackbar's `Value` property changes to one of the values you want to display a tooltip for. Handle the [`ValueChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged.aspx) of the `TrackBar` control to know when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a balloon tooltip

```
ToolTip btt= new ToolTip(); 

btt.ToolTipTitle = "Tooltip"; 
btt.UseFading = true; 
btt.UseAnimation = true; 
btt.IsBalloon = true; 
btt.ShowAlways = true; 
btt.AutoPopDelay = 5000; 
btt.InitialDelay = 1000; 
btt.ReshowDelay = 500; 


btt.SetToolTip(button3, "Clicked.");
```

Comment: Yeah, except that this doesn't satisfy *any* of the requirements laid out in the question. It doesn't appear only when the trackbar is positioned on certain values, and it doesn't appear that particular (x, y) coordinate on the trackbar.

Comment: Well. I think you have to use TooTip class to show the tooltip (you should force to show the tooltip) when your trackbar reach desired value.