# Is there any way to do something like Slider.AutoToolTipPlacement in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm wondering if there is any way to have the value of a slider displayed in tooltip when the thumb is moved on a slider in winforms?  It seems to be doable in wpf ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.autotooltipplacement(v=vs.110).aspx)).  Right now I'm just displaying it in a text box to the side, but I would like a more visually minimal way of doing it.  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a tooltip showing the value of a trackbar in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892369/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-showing-the-value-of-a-trackbar-in-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a [Trackbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z8yazex(v=vs.110).aspx) and a [Tooltip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) in your form, you could use the following code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.trackBar1.ValueChanged += trackBar1_ValueChanged;
    }

    void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Force the ToolTip text to be displayed whether or not the form is active.
        toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;

        // Set up the ToolTip text for the Button and Checkbox.
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.trackBar1, trackBar1.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```